# How do I reference a column that uses an aggregate function in the outer table inside a case statement?

Tags: mysql, function, case, aggregate

I get this error when executing this query: "#1111 - Invalid use of group function"

```
SELECT c.`id_c`, week(date) AS `week`, YEAR(date) AS `year`, COUNT(mood) AS `moodNumber`, AVG(mood) AS `moodAverage`, 
    IF(COUNT(mood) > 2, 
        SUM(CASE WHEN AVG(m.`mood`) > 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
        , 0) AS `usersGoodMood`
FROM Mood AS m
INNER JOIN Cluster AS c ON (m.`nom_c` = c.`nom_c`)
GROUP BY week(date), YEAR(date), m.`nom_c`
ORDER BY `week` ASC
```

I can't seem to figure out a way to reference the column `AVG(mood) AS moodAverage` in the outer table `Mood AS m` within the case statement `CASE WHEN AVG(m.mood) > 3`. I've tried using a subquery but it ends up being too slow to the point that it crashes the database.

How do I solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is mood in your table? a column or a table?

Comment: "Mood" is a table. "mood" is a column within the table.

Comment: Would that be an issue? Just for clarification, the tables are the way it is from another developer. I am helping a client with an existing database. Either way, I don't see how that can cause the issue that I am having.

Answer (score 0):

try to change

```
AVG(mood)
```

into

```
AVG(m.mood)
```

Comment: I tried renaming the column to `moodValue` and tried both AVG(m.`moodValue`) and `moodAverage` in the case statement but I'm still getting the same error messages.

Comment: use **m.** and **c.** in every column you are including in your select statement because you are using join

Comment: Either one gives me the error message "#1111 - Invalid use of group function"